# Fine Uploader only uploads null with asp.net MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, fine-uploader

I have a piece of MVC asp.net `C#` that uses `FineUploader`. I used it in `PHP` before with no issues, but in asp.net c# mvc it fails (it triggers but always posts null) can anyone shed light onto why? I think it's the default transport is imprecise and it's not really using `IFormFile` but without any documentation from `FineUploader` it's impossible to know what structure they rely on for transport - regardless the c# controller fires correctly, but has null in it.

Here is the `<head>` markup

```
 <!-- Fine Uploader Gallery CSS file
====================================================================== -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fine-uploader/fine-uploader-new.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fine-uploader/fine-uploader-gallery.css" />


<!-- Fine Uploader JS file
====================================================================== -->
<script src="/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.core.js"></script>
<script src="/fine-uploader/fine-uploader.js"></script>    

<!-- Fine Uploader Gallery template
====================================================================== -->
<script type="text/template" id="qq-template-gallery">
    <div class="qq-uploader-selector qq-uploader qq-gallery" qq-drop-area-text="Drop files here">
        <div class="qq-total-progress-bar-container-selector qq-total-progress-bar-container">
            <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-total-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar qq-total-progress-bar"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-drop-area-selector qq-upload-drop-area" qq-hide-dropzone>
            <span class="qq-upload-drop-area-text-selector"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="qq-upload-button-selector qq-upload-button">
            <div>Upload a file</div>
        </div>
        <span class="qq-drop-processing-selector qq-drop-processing">
            <span>Processing dropped files...</span>
            <span class="qq-drop-processing-spinner-selector qq-drop-processing-spinner"></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="qq-upload-list-selector qq-upload-list" role="region" aria-live="polite" aria-relevant="additions removals">
            <li>
                <span role="status" class="qq-upload-status-text-selector qq-upload-status-text"></span>
                <div class="qq-progress-bar-container-selector qq-progress-bar-container">
                    <div role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" class="qq-progress-bar-selector qq-progress-bar"></div>
                </div>
                <span class="qq-upload-spinner-selector qq-upload-spinner"></span>
                <div class="qq-thumbnail-wrapper">
                    <img class="qq-thumbnail-selector" qq-max-size="120" qq-server-scale>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="qq-upload-cancel-selector qq-upload-cancel">X</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-upload-retry-selector qq-upload-retry">
                    <span class="qq-btn qq-retry-icon" aria-label="Retry"></span>
                    Retry
                </button>

                <div class="qq-file-info">
                    <div class="qq-file-name">
                        <span class="qq-upload-file-selector qq-upload-file"></span>
                        <span class="qq-edit-filename-icon-selector qq-edit-filename-icon" aria-label="Edit filename"></span>
                    </div>
                    <input class="qq-edit-filename-selector qq-edit-filename" tabindex="0" type="text">
                    <span class="qq-upload-size-selector qq-upload-size"></span>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-delete-selector qq-upload-delete">
                        <span class="qq-btn qq-delete-icon" aria-label="Delete"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-pause-selector qq-upload-pause">
                        <span class="qq-btn qq-pause-icon" aria-label="Pause"></span>
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="qq-btn qq-upload-continue-selector qq-upload-continue">
                        <span class="qq-btn qq-continue-icon" aria-label="Continue"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <dialog class="qq-alert-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Close</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-confirm-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">No</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Yes</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>

        <dialog class="qq-prompt-dialog-selector">
            <div class="qq-dialog-message-selector"></div>
            <input type="text">
            <div class="qq-dialog-buttons">
                <button type="button" class="qq-cancel-button-selector">Cancel</button>
                <button type="button" class="qq-ok-button-selector">Ok</button>
            </div>
        </dialog>
    </div>
</script>
```

Here is the `<body>` markup

```
        <!-- Fine Uploader DOM Element
            ====================================================================== -->
        <div id="fine-uploader-gallery"></div>

        <!-- Your code to create an instance of Fine Uploader and bind to the DOM/template
               ====================================================================== -->
        <script>
            var galleryUploader = new qq.FineUploader({
                element: document.getElementById("fine-uploader-gallery"),
                template: 'qq-template-gallery',
                request: {
                    endpoint: '@Url.Action("UploadFile", "Home")'
                },
                thumbnails: {
                    placeholders: {
                        waitingPath: '/fine-uploader/waiting-generic.png',
                        notAvailablePath: '/fine-uploader/not_available-generic.png'
                    }
                },
                validation: {
                    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png']
                }
            });
        </script>
```

Here is the `HomeController.cs` controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UploadFile(IFormFile file)
    {
        if (file != null)
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(file.OpenReadStream()))
            {
                string contentAsString = reader.ReadToEnd();
                byte[] contentAsByteArray = GetBytes(contentAsString);
                return File(contentAsByteArray, file.ContentType);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I know it fires the server because when I upload three items the controller fires 3 times. But all null.

[image: FineUploader failing]

incidentally, for bonus points, I am also always getting the following console errors even though the files paths are correct

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: yes, basically, the `IFormFile` is wrong ...I used the `FormCollection` and found the file in there as a param by `F9`'ing the objcet.. then IIRC I wrote it as  above, as a byte array, I don't have the exact code any more as I changed jobs. ***BONUS***the other two issues, I just added those two `png` files from fine-uploader (they are there) I have no idea why they are important (they didn't look ever used) but it shut the error up

Comment: Found solution for ASP.Net Core. I used `IFormFile`. Here is my example - https://github.com/ellavs/Fine-Uploader-ASP.NET-Core-2-Example/

Answer (score 3):

1. By default, Fine Uploader will send the file in the body of a multipart encoded POST request. You can use `Request` object instead of method parameters.
2. The server should return valid JSON response to all requests.

   ```
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult UploadFiles()
   {
       string path = Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/");

       var fileExists = Request.Files.Count > 0;

       if (fileExists)
       {
           if (!Directory.Exists(path)) Directory.CreateDirectory(path);

           try
           {
               HttpPostedFileBase fileBase = Request.Files[0];
               if (fileBase != null)
               {
                   string fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileBase.FileName);
                   fileBase.SaveAs(path + fileName);
               }

               return Json(new { success = "true"});
           }
           catch (Exception ex)
           {
               return Json(new { success = "false", error = ex.Message });
           }
       }
       return Json(new { success = "false"});
   }
   ```